# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver: method <init>()V not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, resteasy, spring-bean

I am developing **Spring + MVC + RestEasy** example. I was successfully able to developed the code, but I see the below error. It looks like to dependency mismatched issue. I already frusted to solve this issue, but unable to fixed it yet. I uploaded source code here: **https://github.com/test512/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:778)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:632)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver.<init>(PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.getDefaultArgumentResolvers(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    ... 29 more

Dec 23, 2016 6:25:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [springmvc-hibernate-resteasy] in web application [/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver: method <init>()V not found
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver.<init>(PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.getDefaultArgumentResolvers(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:591)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:778)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:632)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:551)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:492)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5337)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>in.bench.resources</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate</name>
    <description>RestEasy : Integrating with Spring-MVC-Framework and Hibernate ORM</description>


    <properties>
        <resteasy.version>3.0.8.Final</resteasy.version>
        <resteasy.scope>compile</resteasy.scope>        <!-- compile(Tomcat) / provided(JBoss) -->
        <spring.version>4.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version> <!-- 4.x doesn't work with RestEasy directly -->
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.32</mysql.version>
        <validation-api.version>1.1.0.Final</validation-api.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate-validator.version>

        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <compileSource>1.7</compileSource>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <!-- RESTEasy JAX RS Implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>${resteasy.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Resteasy Servlet Container Initializer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>${resteasy.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Resteasy JAXB Provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>${resteasy.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Resteasy Jackson Provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>${resteasy.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- RESTEasy JAX RS Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>${resteasy.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Resteasy Spring Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Validations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySql-Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- servlet-3.1.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL for JSP pages -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 3. logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <finalName>RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate</finalName>

        <!-- maven compiler plugin -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- JAXB plugin to generate-sources from XSD -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal><!-- xjc/generate -->
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/generated/java/source</outputDirectory>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/com/resteasy/series/spring/mvc/hibernate/service/entities</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaFiles>*.xsd</schemaFiles>
                            <schemaLanguage>XMLSCHEMA</schemaLanguage>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                            </args>
                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                    <version>0.6.4</version>
                                </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**springmvc-hibernate-resteasy-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Import basic SpringMVC Resteasy integration -->
    <import resource="classpath:springmvc-resteasy.xml" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <!-- to activate annotations in beans already registered in the ApplicationContext -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.resteasy.series.spring.mvc.hibernate.repository" />

    <!-- to activate MVC annotation -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- scans packages to find and register beans within the ApplicationContext -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.resteasy.series.spring.mvc.hibernate.*" />

    <!-- turn on spring transaction annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.resteasy.series.spring.mvc.hibernate.model"/>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${mysql.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${mysql.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <!-- dataSource configuration -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.password}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Please let me know if you need any other details. I really need help.** I think this is very typical issue when working with resteasy + spring. Isn't it ?

Dependency Tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate ---
[INFO] in.bench.resources:RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate:war:1.0
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:jar:3.0.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:3.0.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-servlet-initializer:jar:3.0.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.resteasy:async-http-servlet-3.0:jar:3.0.8.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxb-provider:jar:3.0.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:2.16:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.12:compile
[INFO] |        \- javax.xml.bind:jsr173_api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson-provider:jar:3.0.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:jar:3.0.8.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-spring:jar:3.0.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jettison-provider:jar:3.0.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.3.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:jar:1.2.0.Beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:4.3.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:3.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.32:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.12:compile
[INFO] \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]    \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.697s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 23 18:59:14 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/494M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Generally conflicting jars is the issue. Use `mvn dependency:tree` and check the Spring jars. Fix the conflicting ones.

Comment: You are at least mixing Spring 4.2.4 and 4.2.8... You are also mixing SLF4J versions

Comment: Check your actual artifact to see what libs are included. Also judging from the doc `resteasy-spring` used Spring 3.0.6 which is quite old, so not sure how compatible that is with Spring 4.2.

Comment: The missing class is located in the spring-web dependency, which is not included in the pom.xml. So you should add this dependency as well.

Comment: No suggested option is working. I uploaded my code in the github above post: https://github.com/test512/RestEasy-Spring-MVC-Hibernate

Comment: I've downloaded your code, adapted the database connection, created the war file, deployed the war and started the application on a jboss 7 server. I didn't get any error.

Comment: Please try it on tomcat. Issue coming on tomcat

Comment: I did the same with a tomcat 8 server. Everything works fine. Did you try to clean the project, tomcat and the tomcat work directory as suggested?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My mistake was that I forgot to add the @Autowired annotation to a constructor.

In my particular case I was trying to configure a CommandLineRunner with final field which was a @Service class.

After correctly adding the @Autowired annotation to MyCommandLineRunner the exception disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

you can resolve the issue by cleaning project, cleaning Tomcat and cleaning Tomcat Work dir. also Make sure you don't have multiple jar files with different versions of Spring in your pom.xml.

Comment: This seems more like a comment then an answer